# Kubernetes API: How to add/remove label from Node

Tags: kubernetes

Through the REST API I am able to GET Node's details through:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/nodes/{Node Name}
```

However, I want to add a new label and delete an old one. Say add label `app=service`, and remove `backend=database`, What type of request am I supposed invoke and what's the JSON format am I required to send?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a new label with the only one request.

JSON is:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "labels": {
            "app": "service"
        }
    }
}
```

You should send `PATCH` request to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/nodes/<node_name>
```

So, finally we have:

```
curl -k -v -H "Accept: application/json" -XPATCH -d '{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"service"}}}' -H "Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json" http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/nodes/<node_name>
```

Comment: I was missing the `Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json` it seems! Was hoping to somehow delete a label too, but it works kind of similar to just rename the key.

Comment: Would this remove all the labels, set to this node previously? Or just add a new one?

Comment: @cardinal-gray Above method adds a new label. All the labels which were set to the node previously are still there.

Answer (score 2):

```
curl -X PATCH \   <cluster end point>/api/v1/nodes/<node name> \   -H 'Authorization: Bearer <your token>' \   -H 'Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json' \   -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \   -d '{
    "metadata": {
        "labels": {
            "name": "vaibhav"
            }
        }
        }
      '
```

This works for me on eks, If your end cluster endpoint is insecure just add "--insecure" in your curl command.

Bearer token is: eks-admin-token(k8s secret)in your kube-system namespace or you can create one with restricted access.

Important thing to note: **Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json**